# Asymmetric delta potential well modelling wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, dirac-delta-distributions

I'm trying to model the wave function for an asymmetric delta function potential well, in which the left side of the well is at a potential of $0$, however the right side of the well has been moved down to $-5U$. Considering free particles of energy  $E_1 = -2U$ and $E_2 = -6U$, what would their wave functions look like? Obviously to the left of the well for $E_1$ it is a positive exponential curve up to $0$, then on the right I would expect it to have a sinusoidal wave function as $E_1 > -5U$, so the particle can be found here. For $E_2$ I would expect the wave function to the left to be a positive exponential curve and the right to be an exponential decay curve down. Here is a quick sketch I mocked up on what I think is going on, please note that the wave function $\Psi(X)$ is superimposed on to the energy diagram.

[![Asymmetric delta poential well][1]][1]

I am also trying to find out how much more likely it is for the particle of energy $E_2$ to be found to the right of the well than to the left of the well. I presume this has to do with the pre-exponential constant A on each side being different.

Any help is much appreciated, I haven't seen an example like this before and it's stumped me!

Thanks.

Comment: I think the main issue here is that for some reason you want to plot probability density/wave function on the energy axis... In fact, it is always positive, whereas its maximum is determined by normalization. Although in books probability densities are often superimposed on the energy diagrams, it is done only for pedagogical reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes I'm trying to plot the wave function, however I find it easier to superimpose this on top of the energy diagram, I will edit the image to include Psi(X) label on the wave function. Thanks

Comment: I was referring to your text: *For E2 I would expect the wave function to the left to be a positive exponential curve up to -5U and the right to be an exponential decay curve down from -5U to -6U. However I guess on the left the exponential curve could go up to 0 instead of stopping at -5U, unsure on this.* Probability density changes between $0$ and $1$, although in reality its maximum is determined by normalization (but minimum is never less than $0$). And it is not in energy units.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right! I've been so used to seeing superimposed wavefunctions in textbooks that I never thought of it that way. Aside from that, is the right hand side of E1 suitable? Thanks

Comment: Yes, the behavior is as you predict: you have exponents whenever your energy is below the band bottom. The difference is that the factor of the exponent is different on the left and on the right. You can obtain it directly from Schrödinger equation: your potential is a sum of a delta potential and a potential step.

Comment: Ok so that would mean there are two different values for K, one on the left and one on the right?  From which I could find the difference in probability in finding the particle on the left or right. Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: So your potential energy is something like $V=-5\,\delta(x)\,\Theta(-x)$?

Comment: If you consider E1, then I think on the left the probability function will look as usual like an exponential of the form e^{-x} and to the right it will be a sinusoidal curve of the form e^(ikx). They will be joined at the origin at a point, i.e., the maxima will be pointed as the wave function is not differentiable at the origin due to the presence of the delta function.

Comment: In case of E2, on both sides the wave function will look like decaying exponential but with different factors and will have a kink at the point as in case of E1. But it seems to me that here, the pre-exponential constants will be same for both sides and so probability that the particle will be on the left will be equal to that on the right.